# C++: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am cleaning up a toy program I wrote for a class using XCode 5. Part of the assignment was to gain familiarity with dynamic memory allocation (meaning it *must* use `new` and `delete` despite the fact that it would really work fine without it). I am receiving:

`HeapOfStudents(67683,0x7fff769a6310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100300060: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

The error happens:

```
Student::~Student() {
    delete firstName; // <- on this line
    delete lastName;
    delete address;
    delete birthDate;
    delete gradDate;
    delete gpa;
    delete crHours;
}
```

which is being called...

```
int main() {

    string line = "";
    vector<Student> students;


    //
    //Create new students from file
    //
    ifstream data_file ("heapData");

    if (data_file.is_open()) {

        while(getline(data_file, line))
            students.push_back(*new Student(line));  <- inside this call here

        data_file.close();
    }

    else return 0;
```

The full `Student` class is below.

Importantly, I noticed that while each `line` gets correctly pushed to the vector, when the next `Student` gets pushed, the previous `Student` *inside* the vector gets corrupted. I see the `malloc` error always on the third iteration of the loop (the file has 50 lines).

The program runs without exception if I change `vector<Student>` to `vector<Student *>` and `student.push_back(*new Student(line))` to `student.push_back(new Student(line))`.

**My question then is:** Can someone please explain what, on a lower level, is happening inside this loop that creates this error?

My guess is that `*new Student(line)` uses the same pointer each time, so through each iteration, data gets corrupted because it is being freed (although this explanation raises questions), while `new Student` returns a new pointer each time, preserving the data that was passed to `students`. I'm thinking that maybe I need to write a copy constructor... This is just my guess.

Here is the `Student` class. `Address` and `Date` are also custom classes that are fairly similar. I didn't include them because they don't seem to be part of the issue.

```
//Constructors
Student::Student() {

    firstName = new string("Testy");
    lastName = new string("Testerson");
    address = new Address("000 Street St", "", "Citytown", "State", "00000");
    birthDate = new Date("01/02/9876");
    gradDate = new Date("01/02/6789");
    gpa = new string("10.0");
    crHours = new string("300");

}

Student::Student(string FN, string LN, string L1, string L2, string C, string S, string Z, string BD, string GD, string GPA, string Hr) {

    firstName = new string(FN);
    lastName = new string(LN);
    address = new Address(L1, L2, C, S, Z);
    birthDate = new Date(BD);
    gradDate = new Date(GD);
    gpa = new string(GPA);
    crHours = new string(Hr);

}

Student::Student(string line) {
    set(line);
}

//Destructors
Student::~Student() {
    delete firstName;
    delete lastName;
    delete address;
    delete birthDate;
    delete gradDate;
    delete gpa;
    delete crHours;
}

//Member Functions
void Student::set(string line) {

    firstName = new string(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    lastName = new string(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    address = new Address();

    address->setLine1(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    address->setLine2(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    address->setCity(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    address->setState(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    address->setZip(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    birthDate = new Date(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    gradDate = new Date(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    gpa = new string(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

    crHours = new string(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(",")));
    line = line.substr(line.find_first_of(",") + 1, string::npos);

}

void Student::printReport() {

    cout << *lastName << ", " << *firstName << ", " << address->getAddress()
    << ", " << birthDate->getDate() << ", " << gradDate->getDate()
    << ", " << *gpa << ", " << *crHours << endl;

}

void Student::printName() {
    cout << *lastName << ", " << *firstName << endl;
}

string Student::getName() {
    return string(*lastName + ", " + *firstName);
```

**EDIT** Here's the copy constructors and assignment operators I wrote for the student class should anyone be interested in seeing/critiquing them:

```
Student::Student(const Student & student){

    firstName = new string(*student.firstName);
    lastName = new string(*student.lastName);
    address = new Address(*student.address);
    birthDate = new Date(*student.birthDate);
    gradDate = new Date(*student.gradDate);
    gpa = new string(*student.gpa);
    crHours = new string(*student.crHours);

}

Student& Student::operator=(const Student & student) {
    return *new Student(student);
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using pointers here? Just have `firstName` be a `string` instead of a `string *`.

Comment: @cdhowie: See the first paragraph. It's an exercise to study memory management.

Comment: In modern C++ there are no naked pointers.

Comment: This code fragment `*new Student(line)` is inherently a memory leak!  The `new` allocates heap space and returns a (temporary) pointer to it.  The `*` operator dereferences the pointer to access the Student object.  At this point you no longer have a pointer to use in a `delete` statement..

Comment: [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) violation.

Comment: Then you should REALLY follow the rule of three. Trust us. ;)

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? Just curious.

Comment: @Joseph if you *want* to use pointers, you should *store* pointers instead of discarding them. This means you also need corresponding `delete` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not following the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722), so Bad Things will happen if you copy a `Student` object. Specifically, both will contain pointers to the same objects, which both will try to delete - so one will try to delete something that the other has already deleted.

The easiest way to give the class valid copy semantics is to disallow copying, by deleting the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator:

```
class Student {
    Student(Student const &) = delete;
    void operator=(Student const &) = delete;

    // rest of class...
};
```

Otherwise, if you want the class to be copyable, implement these to do something sensible.

Also, this causes a memory leak:

```
students.push_back(*new Student(line));
```

by dynamically creating a `Student`, copying it into the vector, and discarding the only pointer to the dynamic object. If you're storing objects, then push a copy of a temporary:

```
students.push_back(Student(line));
```

Alternatively, you could change the container type to `vector<Student*>`, and remember to delete each object when you remove its pointer. (That's a reasonable thing to do as an exercise in pointer-wrangling, as you say this is, but don't do it in any program you want to maintain.)

Once you've learnt the grisly details of manual memory management, make life easier for yourself by avoiding dynamic allocation unless absolutely necessary and, when you really do need it, always managing it with smart pointers, containers, and other [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) types, not by juggling raw pointers.

Comment: I thought the Rule of Three had been updated with C++11 to the Rule of Five :-)

Comment: @user515430: Not really. You sometimes want special move semantics for efficiency, but the Rule of Three is enough for correctness.

Comment: Your link on the Rule of Three is pointing to your profile, just so you'd know. ;)

Comment: @E_net4: Whoops, too many tabs open. Should go to the right place now.

Comment: So, my intuition was that I needed a copy constructor. Judging by how many times I'm seeing `Rule of Three` on this page, it seems I was right. I know realize that vector::push_back() makes a copy to push.
Thanks!

Comment: Writing copy constructors for each class resolved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is that you are keeping a vector of `Student` objects, instead of a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated objects (of type `Student*` therefore).

Simply replace your `students` variable to `std::vector<Student*> students;`. From then, you can simply `push_back` the pointer created by `new`.

The thing is that `vector` already deals with memory allocation, so the line making the push (that you highlighted in the code) was making a copy of the Student to a position in the vector. The pointer to the dinamically allocated object would become unreachable after that.

As Barmar pointed out, having a vector of pointer also has the advantage of being able to push pointers of subclasses of `Student`. A simple example on that:

```
class PhDStudent : public Student { ... }

students.push_back(new PhDStudent(...));
```

Furthermore, there are many other tweaks you should consider in your class:

- Your constructor is taking `string` parameters by-value, which means they are deeply copied from their origin. Using `const string&` is preferable here, to avoid unnecessary copies.
- As already pointed out by some other answers (by Mike Seymour, cdhowie, Anton Savin and whoever is going to point this out), you should follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). If you want your class to be copiable, you should also implement the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator. If you're using C++11, you can take advantage of a move constructor and a move assignment as well, so as to reduce the number of allocations when moving those objects.

Comment: Using a pointer has the added benefit that you can also push subclasses of `Student` onto the vector, and make use of virtual functions.

Comment: So I think what I didn't realize/know/whatever was the mechanics of vector::push_back(). Now its clear that it's making a copy of what's being passed. Therefore I need to follow `Rule of Three`.

Comment: Just that. Since copies were not being properly made, the program was condemned to have issues later on.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely happening because the default copy and assignment operators do not do the right thing -- they copy the pointers.  So if you create a temporary `Student` somewhere you are going to delete the pointers when that temporary is destructed, while the original still points to the same (now deleted) objects.  When it is destructed, it is going to try to delete pointers that were already deleted, hence the error.

You need to follow the [*rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)): if you need a custom destructor, assignment operator, or copy constructor, you need all of them.

Add the following public members to your class:

```
Student(Student const &);
Student & operator=(Student const &);
```

And define them like so:

```
Student::Student(Student const & other)
{
    firstName = new string(other.firstName);
    // And so on, for each pointer member.
}

Student & Student::operator=(Student const & other)
{
    *firstName = other.firstName;
    // And so on, for each pointer member.

    return *this;
}
```

Note that all of this can be avoided by using `string firstName;` instead of `string * firstName;` -- in that case, the default destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator would do the right thing and you wouldn't need to define any of them.

Further, be aware that your `Address` and `Date` classes could have the same problem!  You have to do these kinds of gymnastics any time you use raw pointers as class members.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that you don't want `Student`s to be copied, but you still want to put them into a `vector`. In C++11 it can be solved by just adding a move constructor:

```
class Student {
public:
    Student() { ...}
    ~Student() {...}
    Student(const Student&) = delete; // optional: will be deleted implicitly

    Student(Student&& other) {
        firstName = other.firstName;
        other.firstName = nullptr;
        // ...
    }
};
```

This way copy constructor and assignment operator will be implicitly deleted, so you'll not be able to make copies. But `vector` and other containers will use move constructor just fine. This of course puts certain limitations on `Student` usage.

```
vector<Student> students;
students.push_back(Student()); // OK, student moves
Student s;
students.push_back(s); // Error: copy constructor for Student is deleted
```